# Jenkins build is getting succeed even though Response Assertion fails

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, functional-testing

I am using Jmeter for API's functional testing. For this, have added Response Assertion.

Even though it's failing but Jenkin's build appeared as Succeed.

Is there any way to mark Jenkin build as Failed when our Assertions are failed?

Please help out on this, let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you launch JMeter in Jenkins, if it's just a [command-line non-GUI execution](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl` then it doesn't produce any [error exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) and this is something Jenkins checks.

The options are in:

1. Migrating to [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) which provides `jmeter-check-results` goal
2. Migrating to [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) which provides [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-your-load-tests-with-pass-fail-criteria-a-guide)
3. And finally you can add a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan and force JMeter to exit by adding the next code in the "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       System.exit(1)
   }
   ```

Comment: If I go for the 3rd option, then it's stopping further execution whenever an error occurs. But I want all threads/cases to be executed, any way around?

Comment: You can use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) in order to pass the information about assertion failures to the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) where you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to exit with non-zero status